# Trying to create code that can read through json files and print off all accounts that match a certain criteria

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have two json files. One named people and one named activity. I put both of these jsons into an array using json_decode. Arrays are named people_array and activity_array.

An example of the people json looks like this:

```
[{"id":"ss-avc1","active":1},{"id":"ss-ght1","active":1},{"id":"ss-jvd5","active":1},{"id":"ss-kuh2","active":1},...
```

An example of the activity json looks like this:

```
[{"id":"ss-avc1","status":0},{"id":"ss=avc1","status":1},{"id":"ss-ght1","status":1},{"id":"ss-avc10","status":1},{"id":"ss-avc11","status":1},{"id":"ss-avc12","status":1},{"id":"ss-ght10","status":1},{"id":"ss-kukh2","status":0},{"id":"ss-kuh2","status":1},{"id":"ss-iuy4","status":1},{"id":"ss-jvd5","status":1},{"id":"ss-avc13","status":1},{"id":"ss-opl4","status":0},{"id":"ss-opl40","status":1}
```

So the people json is just all the users with their id's and that they were active represented by 1.

The activity json shows how many times that id was active, by displaying the id and incrementing a number on the end every additional time it shows up, so like ss-avc1 is the id and the next time it appears its ss-avc10, then ss-avc11 and so on.

What im trying to do is if an id is active on the people array then display all the times they were active by reading through the activity array and printing off every account that the id appears and that the status is 1.

I was able to print out a list of all the id's but thats not what I wanted.  What I wanted was, for each ID in the people array, print out all occurrences that has the same ID in the activity array when status is equal to 1. However the ID's in the activity array are not exactly the same as they have an extra digit on the end of the id (except for the first instance) and increments that last digit every additional time it is there.

Here is what I tried so far but had no luck with: (probably a lot of extra and pointless stuff in here):

```
    $people_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('people.json'));

    $activity_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('activity.json'));


    function BeforeCountTimesActive()
    {
        foreach($people_array as $key2 => $jsons2)
        {
            foreach($jsons2 as $key2 => $value2)
            {
                if($key2 == "id")
                {
                    echo "$key2: $value2";
                    echo "</br>";
                    CountTimesActive($key2, $value2);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function CountTimesActive($key, $value)
    {
        foreach($activity_array as $R_key => $R_jsons)
        {
            foreach($R_jsons as $R_key => $R_value)
            {
                if($R_key == "id" and $R_value == $value)
                {
                    if($R_key == "status" and $R_value == 1)
                    {
                        echo "$R_jsons";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    foreach($people_array as $key => $jsons)
    {
        foreach($jsons as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == "active" and $value == 1)
            {
                BeforeCountTimesActive();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain "no luck" in more detail. What actual output did you get, compared to what you wanted/expected? Give us a proper starting point in terms of an explanation.

Comment: @ADyson what I mean by no luck is that I was able to print out a list of all the id's but thats not what I wanted. I was just broadly stating that it didnt work as intended when I said "no luck". What I wanted was, for each ID in the people array, print out all occurrences that has the same ID in the activity array when status is equal to 1. However the ID's in the activity array are not exactly the same as they have an extra digit on the end of the id (except for the first instance) and increments that last digit every additional time it is there.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to give that extra detail, it's useful. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Ok question should be updated now.

Comment: To complete the [mcve], what is your exact desired output from the sample input?  Please [edit] your question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several nested loops and conditionals.

You don't need to do something like this:

```php
foreach($jsons2 as $key2 => $value2)
{
     if($key2 == "id")
     {
```

If you want to access the value by a specified key, do something like `$jsons2['id']` (if it is an associative array) or `$json->id` (if it is an object, ex: a `stdClass` instance). Otherwise, besides making the code less readable, it's slower because you're transversing the entire associative array instead of taking advantage of the data structure (it essentially allows accessing that data almost directly, like a dictionary).

If you want to access the `$activity_array` data by ID (without the prefix: hyphen and integer) very efficiently, prepare a container for that purpose:

```php
$activeCountById = [];
foreach ($activity as $item) {
    $id = preg_replace('~\d+$~', '', $item->id);
    if (!isset($activeCountById[$id])) {
        $activeCountById[$id] = 0;
    }
    if ($item->status) {
        ++$activeCountById[$id];
    }
}
```

`preg_replace('~(\d+)$~', '', $item->id);` removes the last digits from the ID.

Now it's easy to count each person activity:

```php
foreach ($people as $person) {
    if ($person->active) {
        $id = preg_replace('~\d+$~', '', $person->id);
        $count = $activeCountById[$id] ?? 0;
        echo "'$person->id' activity number: $count.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help and tips you gave. I really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: If I wanted to make each ID unique, so abc is its own ID and abc1 is another ID, and then find the times each of those unique IDs show up, would I just change the '~\d+$~' or get rid of it? Or is there something else I would need to do?

Comment: @Dawson, you would get rid of `preg_replace('~\d+$~', '', $i)` ($i is the either `person->id` or `$item->id`). And use `$person->id` and `$item->id` instead. `preg_replace` replaces a pattern with a string. In this case `''` (empty string). `\d` matches a digit. `+` means: at least one. `^` means: at the end of the line. So: it replaces the digits at the end of the line with '', i.e.: removes them. Was that helpful?